# Laravel 5.2 - Including global scope automatically on create

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So I have a global scope on most of my models that basically says to only return items with a record_status of 1. The implementation of this global scope is very similar to the soft-delete global scope in its implementation.

Unfortunately the database does not default to 1 (and im not allowed to change it) so I was trying to find a way to use this same global scope to default create / save calls to have record_status = 1 if not already defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a base model that others model inherit, then you can add to it:

`protected $attributes = ['record_status' => 1];`

If you have way more models that need the status to be 1 than those who need it to be 0, then only in those models who are following the column's default zero value add:

`protected $attributes = ['record_status' => 0];`

That way you don't need to update 50+ models, since default = 1, instead only "exceptions" will override it with 0.

Comment: I like this.....but what about those couple tables that simply don't have a record_status column?

Comment: I thought about this last night. For those who don't have the column I can simply send an empty array to $attributes. Effectively overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `$attributes` property in your model:

```php
class Records extends Eloquent
{
    protected $attributes = ['record_status' => 1];
}
```

This way your attributes will always be initialized with the `record_status` set to `1`.

Comment: I knew about this, but I don't feel like updating my 50+ models with this. They all already have the Record Status Active trait / global scope added to them so I was hoping to do it in there. EDIT: I'd also prefer not to put this in my base model because there are actually one or two corner cases where this ISN'T used :\